# What is the correct way to do a redirection from www. to the naked domain (Server or App or Domain Provider)?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, redirect, dns

I currently have an app that works with both `www.domain.com` and `domain.com`. Considering that this seems to be bad for SEO, I want it to always redirect to the naked domain.

My app works in this way:

**Server**: Google Cloud Platform (App engine)

**App:** Django

**Domain provider:** Godaddy

As I have researched the redirection can be done from any of these 3 options. So I want to ask: **What is the best option and why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested to do the redirection with GoDaddy on App Engine (An A record for www pointing to @) but when I set my custom domain in App Engine, I noticed that for the www.domain a C Record pointed to ghs.googlehosted.com setting was required in the app engine panel, I omitted that in order to do the redirection in GoDaddy, but the app wouldn't load when visiting from www.domain, a 404 error appeared (Also tried by omitting the addition of the www.domain altogether in app engine settings) So I wasn't able to accomplish this in the same fashion than an app that is hosted in a single server.

I think the easiest way would be to handle this inside the app itself like this [site](https://www.the-swamp.info/blog/google-app-engine-redirection-naked-domain-www/) mentions